# Onmouseover event sound plays after one click on Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have implemented a simple `onmouseover` functionality on a website. When mouse moves through a certain HTML element it plays sound. This works fine in Firefox and Opera but in Chrome it only plays after one click of mouse. My code is below.

```
<audio id="audio" src="files/Powerup.ogg"></audio>
```

---

```
function play()
{
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
}
```

`play()` function is called when `onmouseover` events happens. It is called on `<a href>` element. I have also tried few other variations of this code including the one on W3Schools website. But it is same issue in Chrome, working fine in Firefox and Opera.

Comment: Can you try to re-encode the mp3 files to a lower bitrate ?

Comment: I think chrome only allows audio to be played by an explicit user interaction, such as a click or keydown event.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found an explanation [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/) :

> "Audio streams cannot be loaded unless triggered by a user event. As shown in Listing 11, onmousedown, onmouseup, onclick, and ontouchstart are valid events that will successfully load an audio stream when called within a callback. Note that this is only for loading an audio file; calling play() on a file that has already loaded will work as expected."